# Index characters from an array based on user input

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of the entire alphabet from a to z. I also have an input field. I want to be able to find the index of each character from the input field in the alphabet array but my function doesn't work. I've tried storing the text from the input field into an array, and I've tried using a named function for it as well but neither worked.

```
<input type="text" id="plaintext" placeholder="Plaintext">
<div id="start"><div id="start_text">Start</div></div>
```

```
let plaintext = document.getElementById("plaintext");
let alph = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
let startB = document.getElementById("start");
let plainParser = [];

startB.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for(let i=0; i < alph.length; i++){
        console.log(alph.findIndex( () => plainParser.push(plaintext.value.split(''))));
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to … find the index **of each character from the input field** in the alphabet array

Then instead of looping from 0 to 25:

```
for(let i=0; i < alph.length; i++){
```

you should loop over every character from the input:

```
for (let c of plaintext.value) {
```

> I want to … **find the index of each character** from the input field **in the alphabet array**

You have the character, so find the index:

```
alph.indexOf(c)
```

v‘là.

```
let plaintext = document.getElementById("plaintext");
let alph = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
let startB = document.getElementById("start");

startB.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (let c of plaintext.value) {
        console.log(alph.indexOf(c));
    }
});
```

Comment: That for loop absolutely blows my mind how does it work, please send me a link

Comment: It's a for...of loop. If you want more details see there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Answer (score 1):

A shortcut without needing the array is use the charCode of each character.

`a` starts at 97

```js
const str = 'abc';

for(let s of str){
  console.log(s.charCodeAt(0) - 97);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly refactored version of what I think you are looking for:

```js
const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

const result = document.querySelector(".result");
const plaintext = document.getElementById("plaintext");
const startB = document.querySelector(".start");

startB.addEventListener('click', () => {
 const source = plaintext.value;
  
  result.innerText = '';
 
  if (!source) return;
  
  const indices = [];
  for (let char of source) {
   indices.push(alphabet.indexOf(char));
  }
  
  result.innerText = indices.join(', ');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="plaintext" placeholder="Plaintext">
<button class="start">Start</button>

<div class="result" style="font-family: monospace;"></div>
```